# How to use Tags Service to get Tags associated with a content type in Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I have a page called Careers which lists all the Jobs posted with their tags. After clicking on a job and going to their description, I want to display a list of Similar Jobs. For this, I  am trying to use Tags module of Orchard to get all the Tag Names and put it into a searchbuilder.

```
namespace SimpleJobs.Handlers
  {
    public class SimpleJobsHandler : ContentHandler
    {
        //adding IContentManager and IIndexmanager which performs actual search

        private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
        private readonly IIndexManager _indexManager;
        private readonly ITagService _tagService;

        public SimpleJobsHandler(IRepository<SimpleJobsPartRecord> simpleJobsPartRepository,
            IContentManager contentManager,
            IIndexManager indexManager,
            ITagService tagService
            )
        {
            _contentManager = contentManager;
            _indexManager = indexManager;
            _tagService = tagService;
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(simpleJobsPartRepository));

        }

        //building display shape
        protected override void BuildDisplayShape(BuildDisplayContext context)
        {
            if (context.ContentItem.ContentType == "Jobs")
            {
                var similarJobs = GetSimilarJobs(context.ContentItem);
                if (similarJobs.Any())
                {
                    context.Shape.SimilarJobs = context.New.SimilarJobs(Jobs: similarJobs);

                }

            }

        }

     //getting similar jobs using tags
        private IEnumerable<ContentItem> GetSimilarJobs(ContentItem displayedJob)
        {
            StringBuilder tagStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            var searchBuilder = GetSearchBuilder();



            var simpleJobsTags = _tagService.GetTags();




            foreach (var tag in simpleJobsTags){

                tagStringBuilder.Append(" ");
                tagStringBuilder.Append(tag.TagName);
            }


            var similarItemsIds = searchBuilder
                .WithField("type", "Jobs").Mandatory().ExactMatch()
                .Parse("simplejobs-tags", tagStringBuilder.ToString()).Mandatory()
                .Search()
                .Where(h => h.ContentItemId != displayedJob.Id)
                .Select(h => h.ContentItemId)
                .Take(5).ToList();


            return _contentManager.GetMany<ContentItem>(similarItemsIds, VersionOptions.Published, QueryHints.Empty);

            }

        //to check if the user has lucene type implementer enabled otherwise 
        //return a nullsearchbuilder instead of an error

        private ISearchBuilder GetSearchBuilder()
        {
            return _indexManager.HasIndexProvider()
                ? _indexManager.GetSearchIndexProvider().CreateSearchBuilder("Search")
                : new NullSearchBuilder();
        }
    }
  }
```

This code does not seem to work however. Please advise.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fetch tags associated with a *content type* because content types are just blueprints content items are created from; what you tag is a content item, thus you want to fetch tags associated with a *content item*.

To get items with the same tags you'll have to fetch the tags of the content item in question first:

```
contentItem.As<TagsPart>().CurrentTags
```

Then you can fetch content items having specific tags:

```
tagService.GetTaggedContentItems(tagId)
```

where tagId is the id of a tag fetched from CurrentTags (tags have an Id property).